# How to save scroll position within a div with overflow-y:auto;

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, dom

I've got a column flex div container in my web app which uses `overflow-y: auto;`.

Inside this div I got a table with a scroll bar. I would like to be able to implement an auto refresh to the page. However, if I refresh the page, the scroll position within the div is reset back to the top. I can't find any solution to prevent this happening within a DIV. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Screenie to help explain what I have:

[image: screenshot]

**EDIT - Progress**

```
$('#GridViewContainer').load('claims.php', function() {
    $(this).scrollTop($(this).prop("scrollHeight") - $(this).height());
});
```

This seems to work fine if the page is refreshed. However if I go from `claim.php` to `claim.php?Info=data` by the means of

```
onclick="window.location='claims.php?claimID=<?php echo $row_view_claim['id']; ?>&claimTab=<?php if ( $claimTab != '') { echo $claimTab; }else{ echo 'Info'; } ?>'"
```

It will reset itself. Ideas?

Comment: No overflow-y:auto has no effect.

Comment: The `autoflow-y: auto` in your question probably doesn't have an effect, either. Are you sure it's not a typo? I don't think there is [any such CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference) (try searching in that link). I don't guarantee that this is the _only_ problem, but it's probably a good place to start.

Comment: Hi Andrew I have had a look and nothing that looks helpful in this case. However if you look at my edit I have made progress which actually works on refresh however I would need to work out some sort of cookie system to temp store scroll pos which I can retrieve if I window.location the same page instead of reload()

Comment: Did you mean to write overflow-y:auto instead of autoflow-y:auto?
If so, please correct it in your question.

Comment: Yeah I did, my bad. I meant to say overflow-y:auto; not autoflow!

Comment: For this you have to maintain scrolled value in local storage or pass it in query string or save in cookie and use on next page load to scroll there;

Comment: hi @itzmukeshy7, this was my initial assumption but I was hoping for an example. It would also need to be secure and not open for cross site attacks.